# Please create a new tag for Google Play Billing

Tags: feature-request, tags

[Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview) is a service that lets you sell digital content from inside an Android app, or in-app. Also, there is an API [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview) that developers use to implement Google Play Billing within an app. It would be really helpful to find questions regarding Google Play Billing & its API, if a separate tag is created for it.

I don't have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: What value would this tag serve? Is Google Play Billing even on-topic? Why are the current tags we have insufficient?

Comment: I don't really know what u mean by Google Play Billing being "on-topic".

Comment: Oh and why does it attract a -1?

Comment: Because you didn't explain why we *should* create this tag.

Comment: My bad! Thanks for pointing out. I have edited the tag request and provided explanation of why I think this tag should be created. If it sounds logical and helpful, pl create the tag. Thanks!

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan please read descriptions of tags you've used on the post. This may shed some light on current votes on the post. If it does not help consider searching for "what votes mean on meta"... If that is still not enough - ask new question (clearly showing your research which somehow is for example missing from this post since you've presumably tried https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=create+tag).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We already have 2 different tags on Stack Overflow for this.

[android-billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-billing)

> Android In-app Billing is a Google Play service that lets you sell digital content from inside your applications.
>
> You can use the service to sell a wide range of content, including downloadable content such as media files or photos, virtual content such as game levels or potions, premium services and features, and more.

---

[play-billing-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/play-billing-library)

> Anything specific to Google Play Billing library
>
> This tag was created to ask questions and report feedback specific to Google's Play Billing Library.

You may suggest Tag Wiki improvements if you like.

Comment: I would rather not. It has already cost me 3 reputations. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan objective of this site is to get help and provide help to others. Don't be worried about score and reputation points, they will build up eventually if you are following guidelines.

Comment: @Shahood Votes on Meta don't count.